# Pandas: Transform dataframe to show if a combination of values exists in the orignal Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
 | Col 1 | Col 2 | 
0|   A   |   2   |
1|   A   |   3   |
2|   B   |   1   |
3|   B   |   2   |
```

and I need to transform it into a Dataframe that shows for each combination, of the values in Col 1 and Col 2 if that combination is contained in the original DataFrame:

```
  |  1  |  2  |  3  |
A |False|True |True |
B |True |True |False|
```

Is there a native way in pandas to get this transformation?
I was creating the transformed Dataframe manually, but this is way to slow.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more about the expected output, i don't seem to understand it.

Comment: This is `pd.crosstab(df['Col 1'], df['Col 2']).gt(0)`. Pretty sure it's a dup.

Comment: @QuangHoang Can you find the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `max`:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Col 1')['Col 2'], dtype=bool).rename_axis(None).max(level=0)
print (df)
       1     2      3
A  False  True   True
B   True  True  False
```

Or if possible not missing values in column `Col2` then use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html), for remove index and columns name use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.pivot('Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 1').notna().rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print (df)
       1     2      3
A  False  True   True
B   True  True  False
```

Alternative is possible duplicates and `pivot` failed:

```
df = (df.pivot_table(index='Col 1', columns='Col 2', values='Col 1', aggfunc='size')
        .notna()
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (df)
       1     2      3
A  False  True   True
B   True  True  False
```

Or solution from comments:

```
df = (pd.crosstab(df['Col 1'], df['Col 2'])
        .gt(0)
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

```
df.groupby(['Col 1','Col 2']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).astype(bool)

Col2      1     2      3
Col1                    
A     False  True   True
B      True  True  False
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a pivot solution:

```
(df.pivot('Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 1').fillna(0) != 0).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

```
         1     2      3
A      False  True   True
B       True  True  False
```